idle when using Pandas-on-spark apply() to parallelize big data cleaning (can't load in memory)
First, I'm working on azure-Databricks, the dataset can't be load into memory... so maybe an other way more efficient or more simple exist...
I'm trying to use Pandas-on-Spark to parallelize big data clean up. I try many thing but always get error or code to idle.
My strategy is to build an index (indx_df) with pandas-on-spark to parallelize the filtering process, where cores will take chuncks size from indx_df (6 row at time in this case)
This code is my last try, this one stay on idle or make the job but without parallelism (I try it on a small simple of the original :
path_table = 'my_path_to_data'
nb_pas_temps_itt = 6
kelvin = 273.15
t2m_min_max = {'min': -10 + kelvin, 'max': 10 + kelvin}

ds = xr.open_dataset(path_era5_time, engine='zarr', consolidated=True, chunks={})

Where ds is an xarray like this:

time_size = ds.sizes['time']
indx = [pd.Series(np.arange(i, min(i + nb_pas_temps_itt, time_size))) for i in range(0, time_size, nb_pas_temps_itt)]
# to test on small part of the big data ([9:12])
indx_df = ps.DataFrame(indx[9:12])

indx_df looklike this:


def clean_chunk(idx):
    # some filtering to reduce the dataset
    ds_bite = ds.isel(time=idx).to_dataframe()
    ds_bite = ds_bite[ds_bite['ptype'] != 0]
    ds_bite = ds_bite[ds_bite['tp'] > 0.001]
    ds_bite = ds_bite.dropna()
    ds_bite = ds_bite[ds_bite['t2m'].between(t2m_min_max['min'], t2m_min_max['max'])]
    if not ds_bite.empty:
        try: # append data if table exist
            write_deltalake(f"/mnt/{path_table}/{table_name}", ds_bite, mode="append")
            
        except: #create table if not existing
            write_deltalake(f"/mnt/{path_table}/{table_name}", ds_bite)

indx_df.apply(clean_chunk, axis=1)


I found this suggestion, adding hints to my "apply". But I'm not sure if it is necessary due to saving my data to delta table and not returning the dataframe??
clean_chunk(idx) -> pd.DataFrame[zip(indx_df.columns, indx_df.dtypes)]

and got this error...:
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: PySparkRuntimeError: [CONTEXT_ONLY_VALID_ON_DRIVER] It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py:559, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
558 try:
--> 559     return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
560 except pickle.PickleError:
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py:569, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
567     msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.class.name, emsg)
568 print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 569 raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
Anyone see the prob? maybe I'm wrong all the way, this is my firts attempt to parallelize with pandas-on-spark
